# Create scikit Confusion Matrix on the basis of Keras CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn

I have trained my model with a dataset of 15 different sorts of fruits. Everything works fine and the score of accuracy is normaly above 90%.

But if I want to create the Confusion Matrix regarding my CNN, the values do not make any sense as the do not reflect the high accuracy and I don't know why as I tried already different ways of implementing.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

train_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory='training_data/',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256))

validation_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory='validation_data/',
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(256, 256))

#create model
model = Sequential()

#add 2 convolutional layers
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", input_shape=(256, 256, 3), name = "conv1"))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name = "conv2"))

#add the pooling layer
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), name="pooling1"))


#add 2 convolutional layers
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name = "conv3"))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", padding="same", name = "conv4"))

#add the pooling layer
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), name="pooling2"))

#add the flattening layer
model.add(Flatten())

#add the fully connected layer
model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu", name="fc1"))

#add dropout layer
model.add(Dropout(0.2, name="dropout2"))

model.add(Dense(15, activation="softmax")) 
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=SGD(lr=0.00001, momentum=0.9), metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_ds, epochs=10, verbose=1)

score = model.evaluate(validation_ds, verbose=0)
print(f'Test loss: {score[0]} / Test accuracy: {score[1]}')

Y_pred = tf.concat([x for x, y in validation_ds], axis=0)
y_pred = model.predict(Y_pred)
predicted_categories = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

y_true = tf.concat([y for x, y in validation_ds], axis=0)
true_categories = tf.argmax(y_true, axis=1)

print(confusion_matrix(true_categories, predicted_categories))
print(classification_report(true_categories, predicted_categories,))
```

And here you can see the values of the current implementation. The accuracy is 80% as I lowered the amount of epochs for Testing:

```
[[ 9  3 10  2  5  5  8 19  1 12  5 11  1  6 11]
 [ 9  1  8  5  5  6  7 10  3 15  5 12  3  8  7]
 [11  2 10  5  2  5  7  6  2 15  8 11  9  7  8]
 [13  2  7  5  4  5 10 11  1 11  8  7  4  8  6]
 [ 9  3  7  6  4  9  5 13  3 16  4 11  3  7  3]
 [12  4  6  2  2  4 10 18  2 11  8 10  1 11  7]
 [10  2  8  5  3  9  4  8  4 11  7 11  8 11  7]
 [12  1  9  6  5  5  8 16  0 15  6  8  5  8 12]
 [ 9  2  6  5  2  9  9  8  5  8  3 15  8 12  7]
 [10  2  4  6  5 11  9 12  6  6  7  6  5  6  9]
 [ 1  5  5  9  1  7 13 11  4 11  9 10  7  7  8]
 [10  1  9  1  3  8  8  7  2 13  5  8 11  9 13]
 [ 8  1  8  3  5  6  9 11  5 12  8  8  4  7  5]
 [ 8  2  5  4  3  8 11  7  5 11 17  8  5 12  6]
 [13  2  7  6  3 12  9 12  1 11  7  7  6  4  8]]
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.08      0.06      0.07       144
           1       0.01      0.03      0.01        33
           2       0.09      0.09      0.09       109
           3       0.05      0.07      0.06        70
           4       0.04      0.08      0.05        52
           5       0.04      0.04      0.04       109
           6       0.04      0.03      0.03       127
           7       0.14      0.09      0.11       169
           8       0.05      0.11      0.07        44
           9       0.06      0.03      0.04       178
          10       0.08      0.08      0.08       107
          11       0.07      0.06      0.06       143
          12       0.04      0.05      0.04        80
          13       0.11      0.10      0.10       123
          14       0.07      0.07      0.07       117

    accuracy                           0.07      1605
   macro avg       0.06      0.07      0.06      1605
weighted avg       0.07      0.07      0.07      1605

Test loss: 0.9647821187973022 / Test accuracy: 0.813707172870636
```

[Current values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5lwy.png)

Comment: You could directly get predictions with `predict()` and true classes with `generator.classes`. I did not understand why did you use `concat`.

Comment: Hard to judge without access to the data but: Y_pred and y_true shouldn't have the same shape due to softmax. The fact that you treat them the same makes me suspect that you're argmaxing the wrong dimension. Pretty sure that if you start the debugger, you'll probably see that y_pred has non-class values.